# Sonata Media Bundle Template in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony4, sonata-media-bundle

I have installed Sonata Media Bundle in Symfony 4 and all is correct, but something is different respect t Symfony 3.

I can't see the service in Sonata Admin and when I add the sonata media bundle field to an Admin Class this shows a different template.

Here images:

[Sonata Media Bundle template - Symfony 4, in User Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTpbF.png)

[Sonata Media Bundle template - Symfony 3, in User Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw6Mq.png)

[Sonata Media Bundle template - Symfony 3, Adding new image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpwuW.png)

As you can see the template is not working in Symfony 4 or I'm missing something in my code.

My Sonata Media config

sonata_media.yaml

```
    sonata_media:
            class:
                media: App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
                gallery: App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
                gallery_has_media: App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
            default_context: default
            contexts:
                default:
                    providers:
                        - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                        - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                        - sonata.media.provider.image
                        - sonata.media.provider.file
                        - sonata.media.provider.vimeo

                    formats:
                        small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
                        big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}

            cdn:
                server:
                    path: /upload/media

            filesystem:
                local:
                    # Directory for uploads should be writable
                    directory: "%kernel.project_dir%/public/upload/media"
                    create: false


            providers:
                # ...
                file:
                    # the resizer must be set to false, otherwhise this can delete icon files from the fs
                    resizer:    false
                image:
                   thumbnail: sonata.media.thumbnail.format          # default value
        #           thumbnail: sonata.media.thumbnail.consumer.format # can be used to dispatch the resize action to async task
        #            thumbnail: sonata.media.thumbnail.liip_imagine    # use the LiipImagineBundle to resize the image
                vimeo:
                    thumbnail: sonata.media.thumbnail.format          # default value
        #           thumbnail: sonata.media.thumbnail.consumer.format # can be used to dispatch the resize action to async task
        #           thumbnail: sonata.media.thumbnail.liip_imagine    # use the LiipImagineBundle to resize the image
                youtube:
                    thumbnail: sonata.media.thumbnail.format          # default value
        #           thumbnail: sonata.media.thumbnail.consumer.format # can be used to dispatch the resize action to async task
        #           thumbnail: sonata.media.thumbnail.liip_imagine    # use the LiipImagineBundle to resize the image
                dailymotion:
                    thumbnail: sonata.media.thumbnail.format          # default value
        #           thumbnail: sonata.media.thumbnail.consumer.format # can be used to dispatch the resize action to async task
        #           thumbnail: sonata.media.thumbnail.liip_imagine    # use the LiipImagineBundle to resize the image
```

My User's Admin Class

```
    // src/Admin/OgaUsersAdmin.php
    namespace App\Admin;

    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
    use Sonata\MediaBundle\Form\Type\MediaType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

    class OgaUsersAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
    {
        protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
        {
            $formMapper->add('userFirstName', TextType::class)
                       ->add('userCollection', MediaType::class, array(
                             'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image',
                             'context'  => 'default'
                            ));

        }

        protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
        {
            $datagridMapper->add('userFirstName');
        }

        protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
        {
            $listMapper->addIdentifier('userFirstName');
        }
    }
```

My Users Entity and Media Bundle field

```
    namespace App\Entity;

    use Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * OgaUsers
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="oga_users", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="memb_id_idx", columns={"memb_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="comp_id_idx", columns={"comp_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="u_ui_id_idx", columns={"user_collection"})})
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class OgaUsers
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        private $userId;

        /**
         * @var Media
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media")
         * @ORM\JoinColumns({
         *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userCollection", referencedColumnName="id")
         * })
         */
       private $userCollection;
```

Getter and Settter

```
public function getUserCollection(): ?\App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
{
    return $this->userCollection;
}

public function setUserCollection(?\App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media $userCollection): self
{
    $this->userCollection = $userCollection;

    return $this;
}
```

Thank's

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This site is targeted towards programming questions, not software installation.  You might have better luch on linux or server admin sites.  Also you want to avoid putting links to images, if these are removed at some point, the quesiton will become useless for someone with the same problem.

Comment: Thank's for the comment, this is not for instalation, is referent to php framework, and config of a plugin/bundle. I'l try to explain without links to images.

Comment: But you didn't even show us some code, so the objection from @Nic3500 is legit. Did you tried the corresponding tutorials?

Comment: Sorry you are right, I have added the code, and yes I have tried the corresponding tutorial, all is working fine but the template is not as expected, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search for some weeks.

I have the answer.

First I need to add this line to my sonata_media.yaml, to see the Media Library in Admin Dashboard.

```
db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr it is mandatory to choose one here
```

After in Admin in configureFormFields, just need to add ***ModellistType::class***, to the media field.

```
class OgaUsersAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('userFirstname', TextType::class)
                   ->add('userImage', ModelListType::class);
    }
```

Hope it helps!!